# fiscal printer for iOS

Tags: ios, printing

I'm developing an iOS application for a bar, it will be used by the waitress, when the an order it's completed the application should be able to print the receipt using a fiscal printer.

I've never done something like this. does any of you have any experience? 
would you be able to suggest a specific device that allow an easy integration with an iOS app? are there any standard protocol?

Comment: And if someone here did have experience, what do you want to ask them? (As in what's your *real* question?)

Comment: good point, sorry. Edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two SDKs distributed by printers manufacturers that work great with the iPhone:

- http://www.crs-usa.com/softsnbc.asp - this one works with SNBC BTP models, and the printer should have Wi-Fi or a Ethernet cable to connect to the same network.
- http://www.starmicronics.com/ios-android.htm - this one works with Star printers (the same ones Square uses)

In both cases, the SDK needs to get connected to the printer IP, and this can be quite tricky/complicated in the beggining.

But I would start deciding which printer to buy/support, and then start implementing it.